# Flutter Textfield text not getting pasted in proper manner

Tags: flutter

**I receive my otp over the mail and when I try to paste the otp only the first char gets pasted.**

```
class OtpTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  final int lengthOfTextField;
  final List<TextEditingController> textEdittingControllers;
  const OtpTextField(
      {super.key,
      required this.lengthOfTextField,
      required this.textEdittingControllers});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double fem = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 428;
    return

      Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: List.generate(
        lengthOfTextField,
        (i) => SizedBox(
          width: 48 * fem,
          height: 48 * fem,
          child: Center(
            child: TextFormField(
              controller: textEdittingControllers[i],
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              inputFormatters: [
                LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(1),
                FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
              ],
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,

              onChanged: (value) {
                if (value.length == 1 && i <= (lengthOfTextField)) {
                  FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                }
              },



              autofocus: true,
              textInputAction:
                  i == 5 ? TextInputAction.done : TextInputAction.next,
              style: const TextStyle(
                  color: ColorConstant.blackColor,
                  fontFamily: AllFontFamilies.robotoRegular),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                    17 * fem, 13 * fem, 14.0 * fem, 15.0 * fem),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6 * fem),
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                    width: 0.7,
                    color: ColorConstant.darkBlue,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6 * fem),
                ),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                    width: 0.7,
                    color: ColorConstant.blueColor,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                    6 * fem,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Before pasting the otp:

[image: Before pasting the otp]

After:

[image: After]

Answer (score 0):

the problem you're facing is due to the `LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(1)` in your `TextFormField`.
To resolve the issue, you have to implement changes in `onChanged` to paste multiple characters and distribute them across the text fields.

Kind regards,
Marcel